# "no default constructor available in abstract class"

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, default-constructor

I'm getting a no default constructor available error in only one of my concrete classes that implement the same abstract class and I'm not sure why, any help is much appreciated.

`

```
public abstract class Employee implements Payable
    private  String firstName;
    private  String lastName;
    private  String socialSecurityNumber;
    private date birthdate;

          // constructor
          public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,
             String social, date dob )
          {
             this.firstName = firstName;
             this.lastName = lastName;
            this.socialSecurityNumber = social;
             //this.birthdate = getBirthdate();
              // Birthdate(year, month, day);
              birthdate = dob;
          }



public class pieceWorker extends Employee  // no default constructor available
{
    private double wage; `` 
    private int pieces;


    public void pieceWorker(String firstName, String lastName, String social,date dob, double wage, int pieces )  // use some getters ?
    {
        super(firstName,lastName,social, dob );
        setWage(wage);
        setPieces(pieces);
        this.wage = wage;
        this.pieces = pieces;
    }
```

Comment: you're extending a class which doesn't have a no-args constructor, so you need to call the super constructor with the correct arguments (`super(...);`)

Comment: The `void` before pieceWorker needs to be removed.

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo is correct it is your syntax ! Constructors don't need a return type.. They always return its own instance

Comment: By having `void` before `pieceWorker` is making it a method not a constructor.  THEN as you do not have a constructor a default-constructor is automatically created

Comment: Class names should always start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 4):

You've specified a return type of `void` for your constructor. Since constructors can't have return types, you're getting this error because you haven't actually defined a constructor, it's just a regular method.
You'll need to remove `void` from your method in `pieceWorker` to make it a constructor, like this:

```
public pieceWorker(String firstName, String lastName, String social,Date dob, double wage, int pieces )
    {
        super(firstName,lastName,social, dob );
        setWage(wage);
        setPieces(pieces);
        this.wage = wage;
        this.pieces = pieces;
    }
```

Also, unless `date` is a class you've created, you may want to change it to `Date`, in the `java.util` package.

Answer (score 3):

As there is no default (or no-arg) constructor in the parent abstract class the constructor used in sub classes must be specified.

In sub class you do not have a constructor specified as you have add the return type void. Please modify the code as below.

```
public abstract class Employee implements Payable
    private  String firstName;
    private  String lastName;
    private  String socialSecurityNumber;
    private date birthdate;

          // constructor
          public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,
             String social, date dob )
          {
             this.firstName = firstName;
             this.lastName = lastName;
            this.socialSecurityNumber = social;
             //this.birthdate = getBirthdate();
              // Birthdate(year, month, day);
              birthdate = dob;
          }



public class pieceWorker extends Employee  // no default constructor available
{
    private double wage; 
    private int pieces;


    public pieceWorker(String firstName, String lastName, String social,date dob, double wage, int pieces )  // use some getters ?
    {
        super(firstName,lastName,social, dob );
        setWage(wage);
        setPieces(pieces);
        this.wage = wage;
        this.pieces = pieces;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mentioned by @Gulllie and @dammina (almost at the same time), class pieceWorker is having a method

```
public void pieceWorker(args...)
```

and not a constructor. Hence, class pieceWorker will use a default constructor.
The first line of any constructor is call to super(). if you do not explicitly call super(), java will do that for you.

```
public abstract class Employee implements Payable{
private  String firstName;
private  String lastName;
private  String socialSecurityNumber;
private date birthdate;

      // constructor
      public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,
         String social, date dob )
      {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = social;
         //this.birthdate = getBirthdate();
          // Birthdate(year, month, day);
          birthdate = dob;
      }
}
```

you don't have default constructor in above abstract class, as you have defined your own constructor.
Compiler will do following modification to your pieceWorker class.

```
public class pieceWorker extends Employee  // no default constructor available
{
private double wage; 
private int pieces;

// compiler will insert following constructor
public pieceWorker(){
    super();
}

public void pieceWorker(String firstName, String lastName, String social,date dob, double wage, int pieces )  // use some getters ?
{
    super(firstName,lastName,social, dob );
    setWage(wage);
    setPieces(pieces);
    this.wage = wage;
    this.pieces = pieces;
}
}
```

You can do following to make your code work:

```
public class pieceWorker extends Employee  // no default constructor available
{
private double wage; 
private int pieces;

public pieceWorker(String firstName, String lastName, String social,date dob, double wage, int pieces )  // use some getters ?
{
    super(firstName,lastName,social, dob );
    setWage(wage);
    setPieces(pieces);
    this.wage = wage;
    this.pieces = pieces;
}
}
```